# Error al crear etiqueta, no muestra el titulo en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-imagenes

al crear una etiqueta, y darle click en ver en la página no muestra el error, que puede ser, ya busque y no encuentro nada.

la configuración de la etiqueta es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El error al dar en ver etiqueta es el siguiente:** 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si a alguien le sirve yo arregle el problema porque en el tema llamaba un archivo tag-nombretag.php y de esta forma sl crearlo muestra 3l nombre del tag.